# Index error: list index out of range - How to skip a broken URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, index-error

How can I tell my program to skip broken / non-existent URLs and continue with the task? Every time I run this, it will stop whenever it encounters a URL that doesn't exist and gives the error: **index error: list index out of range**.

The range is URL's between 1 to 450, but there are some pages in the mix that are broken (for example, URL 133 doesn't exist).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.DataFrame()

for id in range (1, 450):

      url = f"https://liiga.fi/api/v1/shotmap/2022/{id}"
      res = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
      s = soup.select('html')[0].text.strip('jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014(').strip(')')
      s = s.replace('null','"placeholder"')
      data = json.loads(s)
      data = json_normalize(data)
      matsit = pd.DataFrame(data)
      df = pd.concat([df, matsit], axis=0)


df.to_csv("matsit.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: use try except statement

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1a78d35e61fe> in <module>
     12       res = requests.get(url)
     13       soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
---> 14       s = soup.select('html')[0].text.strip('jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014(').strip(')')
     15       s = s.replace('null','"placeholder"')
     16       data = json.loads(s)

IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume your index error comes from the line of code with the following statement:

```
s = soup.select('html')[0].text.strip('jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014(').strip(')')
```

You could solve it like this:

```
try:
    s = soup.select('html')[0].text.strip('jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014(').strip(')')
except IndexError as IE:
    print(f"Indexerror: {IE}")
    continue
```

If the error does not occur on the line above, just catch the exception on the line where the index error is occuring. Alternatively you can also just catch all exceptions with

```
try:
    code_where_exception_occurs
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception: {e}")
    continue
```

but I would recommend to be as specific as possible, so that you handle all expected errors in the appropriate way.
In the example above replace code_where_exception_occurs with the code. You could also put the try/except clause around the whole block of code inside the for loop, but it is best to catch all exeptions individually.
This should also work:

```
try:
    url = f"https://liiga.fi/api/v1/shotmap/2022/{id}"
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
    s = soup.select('html')[0].text.strip('jQuery1720724027235122559_1542743885014(').strip(')')
    s = s.replace('null','"placeholder"')
    data = json.loads(s)
    data = json_normalize(data)
    matsit = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = pd.concat([df, matsit], axis=0)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception: {e}")
    continue
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you edit how to implement that into the code? It seems I'm getting invalid syntax whenever I try to paste that it.

Comment: There was a syntax error. I fixed it. A bracket was missing.

Comment: Thanks! I should've been more clear, as I have no idea where to insert that piece of code you provided. Still gives invalid syntax error.

Comment: Maybe try to convert all tabs to white spaces. This often happens as a mistake.

Comment: Awesome, now it works. Thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that you get a `204 error` (e.g.: https://liiga.fi/api/v1/shotmap/2022/405) for some of the urls, so simply use `if-statement` to check and handle this:

```
for i in range (400, 420):
    url = f"https://liiga.fi/api/v1/shotmap/2022/{i}"
    r=requests.get(url)
    
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print(f'Error occured: {r.status_code} on url: {url}')
        #### log or do what ever you like to do in case of error
    else:
        data.append(pd.json_normalize(r.json()))
```

**Note:** *As already mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73584487/14460824 there is no need to use `BeautifulSoup`, use `pandas` directly instead to keep your code clean*

##### Example

```
import requests, time
import pandas as pd

data = []
for i in range (400, 420):
    url = f"https://liiga.fi/api/v1/shotmap/2022/{i}"
    r=requests.get(url)
    
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print(f'Error occured: {r.status_code} on url: {url}')
    else:
        data.append(pd.json_normalize(r.json()))

pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)#.to_csv("matsit", index=False)
```

##### Output

```
Error occured: 204 on url: https://liiga.fi/api/v1/shotmap/2022/405
```

Comment: That sounds like an great way to handle this as well. Thank you!